# How to trigger build after release is completed successfully in azure devops?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have build  and release definition in azure-devops. I  want the build to be triggered after release is done, I don't repeat the steps, I want to trigger already existing build definition. I am trying to figure how to do this in azure-devops.

When I tell build it is end to end test. The idea is to run the end to end test after release is done. Note I already have E2E Tests build, here I have repeated the steps, instead I want to just refer the existing build and trigger it. Any suggestion or help on how to do this will be of great help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently supported. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) has all Azure DevOps trigger events. Currently release completion cannot trigger a build.

As a workaround, we could open release definition and add task `power shell` at the end to call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to trigger build.

Power shell script:

```
$token = "{PAT}"   
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))


$JSON = @"
{
  "definition": {
    "id": {Build Definition ID}
  }
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

Also, we could add the extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline)
and then add task `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` at the end of the job to trigger build.

Result:

[image]

Comment: The extension is worked for me.